# Indicate certain points on Line Graphs which are below threshold value in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using below mentioned code, Line graph is obtain. Here, by masking, certain portion of line between points which are below threshold value got Red in colour. However, I want specific points which are below threshold value ("b") should indicate in Red color on line graph instead of portion of line. Any suggestion?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#reading .csv file
Time = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/Temp/%s/Filtered  File.csv'%DayFolder)

a = np.array(Time['Irradiation W/sqm'])

b = int(Time['Irradiation W/sqm'].max()*0.5)
# use a masked array to suppress the values that are too low
a_masked = np.ma.masked_greater(a, b)

# plot the full line
plt.plot(a, 'k')

# plot only the large values
plt`enter code here`.plot(a_masked, 'r', linewidth=2)

# add the threshold value (optional)
plt.axhline(b, color='k', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([1,2,17,20,16,3,5,4])

# use a masked array to suppress the values that are too low
a_masked = np.ma.masked_greater_equal(a, 15)

# plot the full line
plt.plot(a, 'k')

# plot only the large values
plt.plot(a_masked, 'r', linewidth=2)

# add the threshold value (optional)
plt.axhline(15, color='k', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

try this hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this. I have imported data from csv file and draw graph from column, I will use column in place of variable "a".

Comment: Using this code, certain portion of line get Red. However, I want to highlight that data point on line which are below threshold value. For ex: is I have a=(12,3,15,16,9,18), and my threshold value is 10, then point 3 and 9 should get highlights. Is it possible?

Comment: change the masked_greater_equal to masked_less_equal and put the value 10 in place of 15

Comment: I did it same, however, portion of line between two lesser points get highlighted instead of that particular point.